# Tomcat: Can't start tomcat after installing it on Ubuntu: "Job for tomcat.service failed because the control process exited with error code."

Tags: ubuntu, tomcat

I followed the steps https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-apache-tomcat-8-on-ubuntu-16-04 to install [tomcat 8.5.24](http://apache.cs.utah.edu/tomcat/tomcat-8/v8.5.24/bin/apache-tomcat-8.5.24.tar.gz) on Ubuntu 16.04, till running `sudo ufw allow 8080` in "Step 6: Adjust the Firewall and Test the Tomcat Server".

Then I can't start tomcat,

```
$ sudo systemctl start tomcat
Job for tomcat.service failed because the control process exited with error code. See "systemctl status tomcat.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.
```

and the link `http://localhost:8080/` doesn't work in both firefox and google chrome browsers.

I was wondering how to solve the problem.

The following details are what I followed the above output messages of `sudo systemctl start tomcat`. It seems that `/opt/tomcat/bin/startup.sh` succeeded while `/opt/tomcat/bin/shutdown.sh` failed. Much appreciate your help!

```
$ systemctl status tomcat.service
● tomcat.service - Apache Tomcat Web Application Container
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/tomcat.service; disabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: activating (auto-restart) (Result: exit-code) since Fri 2017-12-01 18:55:30 EST; 2s ago
  Process: 19490 ExecStop=/opt/tomcat/bin/shutdown.sh (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
  Process: 19478 ExecStart=/opt/tomcat/bin/startup.sh (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
 Main PID: 19440 (code=exited, status=127)

Dec 01 18:55:30 ocean systemd[1]: tomcat.service: Control process exited, code=exited status=1
Dec 01 18:55:30 ocean systemd[1]: Failed to start Apache Tomcat Web Application Container.
Dec 01 18:55:30 ocean systemd[1]: tomcat.service: Unit entered failed state.
Dec 01 18:55:30 ocean systemd[1]: tomcat.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.

$ journalctl -xe

-- Unit tomcat.service has begun starting up.
Dec 01 18:51:24 ocean startup.sh[18873]: Existing PID file found during start.
Dec 01 18:51:24 ocean startup.sh[18873]: Removing/clearing stale PID file.
Dec 01 18:51:24 ocean startup.sh[18873]: Tomcat started.
Dec 01 18:51:24 ocean shutdown.sh[18885]: PID file found but no matching process was found. Stop aborted.
Dec 01 18:51:24 ocean systemd[1]: tomcat.service: Control process exited, code=exited status=1
Dec 01 18:51:24 ocean systemd[1]: Failed to start Apache Tomcat Web Application Container.
-- Subject: Unit tomcat.service has failed
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://lists.freedesktop.org/mailman/listinfo/systemd-devel
-- 
-- Unit tomcat.service has failed.
-- 
-- The result is failed.
Dec 01 18:51:24 ocean systemd[1]: tomcat.service: Unit entered failed state.
Dec 01 18:51:24 ocean systemd[1]: tomcat.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Dec 01 18:51:34 ocean systemd[1]: tomcat.service: Service hold-off time over, scheduling restart.
Dec 01 18:51:34 ocean systemd[1]: Stopped Apache Tomcat Web Application Container.
-- Subject: Unit tomcat.service has finished shutting down
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://lists.freedesktop.org/mailman/listinfo/systemd-devel
-- 
-- Unit tomcat.service has finished shutting down.
Dec 01 18:51:34 ocean systemd[1]: Starting Apache Tomcat Web Application Container...
-- Subject: Unit tomcat.service has begun start-up
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://lists.freedesktop.org/mailman/listinfo/systemd-devel
-- 
-- Unit tomcat.service has begun starting up.
Dec 01 18:51:35 ocean startup.sh[18896]: Existing PID file found during start.
Dec 01 18:51:35 ocean startup.sh[18896]: Removing/clearing stale PID file.
Dec 01 18:51:35 ocean startup.sh[18896]: Tomcat started.
Dec 01 18:51:35 ocean shutdown.sh[18908]: PID file found but no matching process was found. Stop aborted.
Dec 01 18:51:35 ocean systemd[1]: tomcat.service: Control process exited, code=exited status=1
Dec 01 18:51:35 ocean systemd[1]: Failed to start Apache Tomcat Web Application Container.
-- Subject: Unit tomcat.service has failed
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://lists.freedesktop.org/mailman/listinfo/systemd-devel
-- 
-- Unit tomcat.service has failed.
-- 
-- The result is failed.
Dec 01 18:51:35 ocean systemd[1]: tomcat.service: Unit entered failed state.
Dec 01 18:51:35 ocean systemd[1]: tomcat.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
```

My Java versions are

```
$ java --version
java 9.0.1
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 9.0.1+11)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 9.0.1+11, mixed mode)

$ javac --version
javac 9.0.1
```

---

**update:**

Instead of `sudo systemctl start tomcat` which gives the error above, if I run

```
cd /opt/tomcat/bin

sudo ./catalina.sh run
```

http://localhost:8080/ shows the correct webpage. SO what is the reason that one doesn't work while the other does?

Comment: Try delete the Tomcat PID file. What could be happening is the ProcessID in the PID file now belongs to another process. Hence the error: `Dec 01 18:51:24 ocean shutdown.sh[18885]: PID file found but no matching process was found. Stop aborted.`

Comment: Thanks. is `18885` the pid of the original tomcat process? I can't find directory `/proc/18885/`. What shall I do to " delete the Tomcat PID file"?

Comment: I updated my post with my java version. i am using Oracle java 9.0.1.

Comment: I updated at the end with some other way.

Comment: The location of the PID file should be `/path-to-catalina-base/PID` or `/path-to-catalina-home/PID`

Comment: in my case it was a permission issue. running sudo chmod -R +x tomcat-directory/ again solved it

Answer (score 13):

Make user **tomcat** owner of the whole tomcat directory:

`cd /opt && sudo chown -R tomcat tomcat/`

Comment: I removed the temp and logs directory from /opt/tomcat directory, so when i created it was set the owner to current user so i needed to change it.

Answer (score 8):

I resolved this issue by removing "**/jre**" from **JAVA_HOME** in `/etc/systemd/system/tomcat.service`

Answer (score 3):

I had this same issue on an existing installation of **Tomcat** on Ubuntu:

I started having this issue when I tried clearing the logs files by making a copy of the existing one and then creating a new one using these commands:

```
sudo cp /opt/tomcat/logs/catalina.out catalina_copy.out
sudo rm -rf /opt/tomcat/logs/catalina.out
sudo touch /opt/tomcat/logs/catalina.out
```

And I was having this error when I tried to start `tomcat` using `sudo systemctl restart tomcat`:

```
$ sudo systemctl start tomcat
Job for tomcat.service failed because the control process exited with error code. See "systemctl status tomcat.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.
```

**Here's how I fixed it**:

The issue was that after I created and made a copy of the files, the ownership for the files was changed from `tomcat` to `root`, which I confirmed by running the command below in the `/opt/tomcat/logs` directory:

```
ls -lh
```

All I had to do was to change the ownership from `root` to `tomcat` by running the command below:

```
sudo chown -R tomcat:tomcat catalina.out
sudo chown -R tomcat:tomcat catalina_copy.out
```

This time when I tried starting the tomcat server using `sudo systemctl restart tomcat` it worked fine.

That's all.

**I hope this helps**

Answer (score 3):

You might have added the following line in your tomcat service:-

> Environment="JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/default-java"

you have to replace it with the actual version of java you are using.
Type the following command in you terminal :-

> sudo update-java-alternatives -l

[output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yBPkM.png)

replace the output of the above command with the JAVA_HOME variable path and your variable should look somewhat like following:-

> Environment="JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk-amd64"

Now reload daemon and restart you service it should be working fine

> sudo systemctl daemon-reload

> sudo systemctl start tomcat

Check the status of service

> sudo systemctl status tomcat

Answer (score 1):

Find JAVA_Home ($env | grep JAVA_HOME)

sudo vi /etc/systemd/system/tomcat.service

Environment="JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-amd64"

Answer (score 1):

Just remove '/jre' from JAVA_HOME in 'tomcat.service' file and the service will start.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered a similar problem today, only difference was that the service was running perfectly until last night and all of a sudden it stopped..

The reason was that the Java version had been updated automatically which changed the java path.

All I had to do was update the new Java path in the tomcat.service file, restart the daemon and viola..!!

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/32792503)

Comment: I do not have a question, I just said what issue I faced and what I did to resolve it.. if someone is facing a similar issue, they can check if that is because of this or not and can work to resolve it..